# Edit on site with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a school assignment that I would love to have a on site edit admin panel.
I coded this but I just cant get it to work properly, as every time I double click in one and then out it replaces the value with the previous value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var bound = $("p").bind("dblclick", function(event) {

            event.stopPropagation();
            var currentEle = $(this);
            var value = $(this).html();
            edit(currentEle, value);
        });
    });

    function edit(currentEle, value) {
        $(currentEle).html('<input class="tedit" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
        $(".tedit").focus();

        $(".tedit").keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                currentEle.parent('p').html($(this).val().trim());
            }
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            var value1234 = $(".tedit").val().trim();
            $("p").removeClass();
            currentEle.html(value1234);

        });
    }

</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x6e16d3n/3/

Comment: Dude I am just in here to ask for some help as I cant find the problem my self if you don't want to help then don't. But why take you time to come in here and start flaming ?

Comment: Your question should show you spent time on problem and stuck on something. not - "I just can't get it work", also upload your code to http://jsfiddle.net/. Describe what exactly not working. So people will ask least questions and just give you help. Remember this site to ask questions/get answers which can be useful for others. Not you personal problem solver.

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to reproduce your problem with the relevant HTML included.

Comment: My problem is that when I double click on a p tag, it should give it the class tedit as it does. But when I click out of the input and into a new on to edit that. I replaces the previous edited p tag with the value of the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because every time you edit you create a new click handler attached to the document that has a reference to the current element at the time of creation.

This handler is still active when you are editing another object and still has a reference to the old element (look up closures to understand why) but is taking the value to add to the p from what ever `.tedit` is on the screen so in the end they all get updated with the same text.

One quick soloution would be to take this click handler out of the dit function and declare it once, check if edit is on the screen and if it is then make the edits parent html equal the value of the input box

```
$(function () {
    var bound = $("p").bind("dblclick", function (event) {

        event.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        edit(currentEle, value);

    });
});

function edit(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="tedit" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
    $(".tedit").focus();

    $(".tedit").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            currentEle.parent('p').html($(this).val().trim());
        }
    });


}

$(document).click(function () {
    if ($(".tedit").length) {
        var value1234 = $(".tedit").val().trim();
        $("p").removeClass();
        $(".tedit").parent().html(value1234);
    }

});
```

example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x6e16d3n/11/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help mate. Appreciate it :)